# what is -o3 optimization flag used in gcc

Tags: gcc

Can someone tell me the simple question why we need to put -o3 associates with -o in gcc to compile c program, simply it will help to increase the speed of compilation or reduced the time lapsed spending in compilation?

Thanks!!!

Comment: the flag is `-O3` not `-o3`, the latter will write the output to a file called `3` which is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

It can potentially increase the performance of the *generated code*.

In principle, compilation usually takes *longer* because this requires (much) more analysis by the compiler.

For typical modern C++ code, the effect of -O2 and higher can be very dramatic (an order of magnitude, depending on the nature of the program).

Precisely which optimizations are performed at the various optimization levels is documented in the manual pages: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Keep in mind, though that the various optimizations can potentially make latent bugs manifest, because compilers are allowed to exploit [*Undefined Behaviour***¹**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to achieve more efficient target code.

Undefined Behaviour lurks in places where the language standard(s) do not specify exactly what needs to happen. These can be extremely subtle.

So I recommend on using anything higher than -O2 unless you have rigid quality controls in place that guard against such hidden undefined behaviours (think of valgrind/purify, statical analysis tools and (stress) testing in general).

---

¹ A very profound blog about undefined behaviour in optimizing compilers is here: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 . In particular it let's you take the perspective of a compiler writer, whose only objective is to generate the fastest possible code that still *satisfies the specifications*.